# Codeigniter get parameters from url?

Tags: codeigniter, url, get

I have one view

```
<div class="panel-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="mytable" class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0"
                       width-="100%">

                    <tbody>

                    <?php
                    foreach ($result as $row) {
                        if ($row->active == 1) {
                            foreach ($countries as $country) {
                                if ($country->id == $row->country) {
                                    if ($this->session->userdata('language') == 3) {
                                        $ccountry = $country->ro_name;
                                    } else if ($this->session->userdata('language') == 2) {
                                        $ccountry = $country->ru_name;
                                    } else {
                                        $ccountry = $country->name;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            $time_sbs = substr($row->time, 0, 5);
                            echo '<tr ">
                        <td width="20%">' . $row->name . '</td>
                        <td width="10%">' . $row->date . ' ' . $time_sbs . '</td>
                        <td width="10%">' . $row->registration_date . '</td>
                        <td width="10%">' . $ccountry . '</td>
                        <td width="10%">' . $row->city . '</td>
                        <td width="10%">' . $row->address . ' </td>
                        <td width="20%">' . $row->description . '</td>
```

I sampled from the database for the date

```
function get_tournaments()
{
    //data is retrive from this query
    $query = $this->ci->db->query("SELECT * FROM tournaments WHERE date > CURDATE() ORDER BY date");
    /*$query = $this->ci->db->query("SELECT * FROM tournaments");*/
    return $query;
}

function get_tournaments_finished()
{
    //data is retrive from this query
    $query = $this->ci->db->query("SELECT * FROM tournaments WHERE date < CURDATE() ORDER BY date");
    /*$query = $this->ci->db->query("SELECT * FROM tournaments");*/
    return $query;
}
```

I need to have one table in the view, but with the help of the get parameter, I showed the tournament maps:

```
<?php echo base_url(); ?>tournaments?type=upcoming",
<?php echo base_url(); ?>tournaments?type=finished"
```

How to check for a get parameter type

Answer (score 3):

In Codeigniter You can check input parameter by using

```
$input_params=$this->input->get();// this will give you all parameters
```

or

```
$single_param=$this->input->get('name_of_the_parameter');// this will give you individual parameter
```

Comment: input->get_post() does not deliver a list of parameters - get() or post() do though.

Comment: this is not working with Codeigniter 4

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$_GET['type'];
```

Or if you prefer, instead of using get, you could use the method parameter to know the type

```
//something like this
//your url will be like this
base_url('tournament/upcoming'); or
base_url('tournament/finished');

//then your controller method will look like this
public function tournament(){
    $type = $this->uri->segment(3);
    //then fetch the data based on the type
}
```

I hope this helps you, if you have any issue, let me know so we can sort it out.